# Unable to build a react native app on xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, mobile

I get this error below when trying to build a react native app on xcode

```
Info.plist Error Unable to process Info.plist at path /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.....app/Info.plist
```

What is info.plist? and how can i go about solving this issue.

I try creating a new Info.plist manually but it isn't working, can xcode automatically create it

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope you are doing well. Info.plist is a file which is created when you initialize a new IOS project (React native project).

It stores all of the info related to permissions and names etc. It is usually location in the IOS folder of your project.

Would be great if you share the info.plist & package.json file here. There is a high chance that there might be something missing or wrong in the file and having an idea of these two files can help in solving the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if an info.plist exists in your Xcode project, if it exists delete the `.../Derived/` files and folder to force Xcode to generate new derived files.
2. If the info.plist is missing in your project generate a new RN (`npx create-react-app`) project and copy it to your project

Answer (score 0):

MAKE SURE '**Run Script**' option is at the **LAST POSITION** in 'Build Phases' pane.
[image]